# How to deal with Android device(lower API 4.1) to support TLS1.2

Tags: java, android, security, ssl

TLSv1.2 is supported by Android SSLSocket on API 16+ according to http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html

But my project want to adapt some devices lower than API 16,and every android network framework depends on Android SDK, so anyone has deal with the same question,there is any executable method?

Any suggestions are thankful!